# uploading flat files from SFTP to S3 using python or node.js

Tags: python, amazon-s3, sftp

I am getting some flat files every 15 minutes in SFTP server. I want to know, how can i send these files to s3 bucket automatically using python or node.js program? And if some python program runs, where should it run? Should there be any kind of job, which runs this program?

Comment: From where are the files coming? Is there any chance that they can be sent direct to S3, rather than going via an SFTP server?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to schedule a script to run on a regular basis on the server (using cron for Linux or a Scheduled Task for Windows).

The script can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which has a `aws s3 cp` command that can transfer files to Amazon S3.

If you wish to use Python or Node instead, there are [AWS SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) available for those languages (and many more) that make it easy to transfer files to Amazon S3.

The server sending the files will also need AWS credentials to authorize the data transfer.

Comment: Hi John, if i make a python/node.js program, where should I run that program? so that it keeps pulling the data from s3 at regular interval and send to s3

Comment: It can run _anywhere on the Internet_. The best place to run it would be on the server that is running SFTP, since it has easy (local?) access to the files. Alternatively, it could run on an Amazon EC2 instance. You could _possibly_ run it on AWS Lambda (without requiring a server), but there is a limit of 512MB disk space, so it would not be suitable if your files are bigger than that size. The totally best option, of course would be to have the original people send it straight to S3 instead of the SFTP server.